# Batch File and Quoting Variables

Tags: windows, batch-file, cmd, environment-variables

I'm working with a batch file and I was wondering, why do some variables have double quotes around them and others don't, for example?

```
SET "keePass=%USERPROFILE%\KeePass\KeePass-2.31\KeePass.exe"
```

but this:

```
SET name="bob"
```

Why the double quotes in the first one, but not the second?

Comment: Remove the spaces around the `=`, independent on where you place the quotation marks! otherwise, they become part of the variable name and the value! In the first example, the `""` are *not* part of the variable value; in the second example (supposing you removed the spaces around `=`), they are part of the value; the first example is best practice, because it avoids trouble with some special characters like `^`, for instance...

Comment: @aschipfl - I see, so it's used for cases where special characters might be an issue?

Comment: Yes, but there are even more advantages: you won't run itno problems with trailing whitespaces (because the closing `"` ends the value), and you can use it in-line with other commands (e. g., `set "var=value" & echo some text`) without having unwanted spaces at the end... I'd always use this syntax, so you have always the same place to take care about quotes, namely during expansion (like `%var%` or `"%var%"`, depending on the usage)...

Comment: Also, when comparing variables (e.g., `if "%var%"=="value"` or `if "%var1%"=="%var2%"`) it's useful to put double quotes around both the variables and the values, if one of the variables is likely to be blank.  Further, when variables have been set to paths and filenames, they should always be referenced surrounded by double quotes to avoid problems with spaces (e.g. `copy "%aFile%" "%aPath%"`).

Answer (score 12, accepted):

...to provide the conclusion at the beginning:

Supposing you have got the command extensions enabled (which is the default setting of the Windows command prompt `cmd`), the best practice is to use the following `set` syntax:

```
set "VAR=value"
```

(The command extensions can be enabled/disabled by `cmd` (type `cmd /?` in a command prompt window for help) or, within batch files only, by `setlocal` (type `setlocal /?` for details).)

---

At first, let us take a look at the standard syntax mentioned in the help text, that appears when typing `set /?` (or `help set`) in a command prompt window:

```
set VAR=value
```

This assigns the string `value` to the variable `VAR` obviously.

The good thing of this syntax is:

- it also works when the command extensions are disabled;
- the variable value is not surrounded by quotation marks (supposing `value` does not contain such on its own), so there is only one place to take care of them, namely during variable expansion (like `%VAR%` or `"%VAR%"`, depending on the situation at hand; this is particularly useful when combining strings like `constant_%VAR%` or `"constant_%VAR%"`, which will be expanded to `constant_value` or `"constant_value"`, respectively, so you always have full control over the placement of the quotation marks; if the value contained the enclosing `""`, `constant_%VAR%` would expand to `constant_"value"`, which might probably not be the string you want to have);

But there might occur some problems:

- any (invisible) trailing white-space becomes part of the string value, so if the command line is followed by a single <kbd>SPACE</kbd> character, `VAR` will carry the value `value`<kbd>SPACE</kbd>;
- when you concatenate this command with another command, like `set VAR=value & echo Text`, the <kbd>SPACE</kbd> before the `&` character becomes part of the value; you could of course write `set VAR=value&echo Some text`, but this was quite difficult to read;
- if `value` contains special characters, like `^` `&` `(` `)` `<` `>` `|`, you might run into problems; for example, `set VAR=1&2` will assign `1` to `VAR`, then an error will arise, because `&` separates two commands and `2` is not a valid one;

---

The syntax of the second example in your question is quite similar:

```
set VAR="value"
```

This assigns the string `"value"` to `VAR`, so the quotation marks are included in the value.

The advantages are:

- it also works when the command extensions are disabled;
- special characters (like `^` `&` etc.) in `value` do not cause any trouble because of the `""`;

But still:

- the quotation marks become part of the value, which may be disturbing in numerous situations;
- unwanted trailing white-spaces (after the last `"`) still become part of the string value;
- again when concatenating this command with another command using `&`, you have to omit spaces around the ampersand;

---

Now, let us check out the syntax of the first example in your question:

```
set "VAR=value"
```

This assigns `value` to `VAR`. Since the quotation marks are placed around the entire assignment expression, they are removed before the assignment is actually accomplished.

This has got several advantages:

- the quotation marks do not become part of the variable value;
- any (unintended) trailing white-spaces do not become part of the variable value;
- you can concatenate it with another command using <kbd>SPACE</kbd>`&`<kbd>SPACE</kbd> without any unwanted spaces being appended to the value;
- special characters (like `^` `&` etc.) in `value` are no problem;

But there is one issue:

- the command extensions need to be enabled for this syntax to work; otherwise, an error arises;

---

Finally, you could also combine the above syntaxes, if you do want the quotation marks to become part of the variable value (although I do not recommend that):

```
set "VAR="value""
```

This assigns `"value"` to `VAR`.

Advantages:

- unwanted trailing white-spaces (after the last `"`) do not become part of the variable value;
- you can concatenate it with another command using <kbd>SPACE</kbd>`&`<kbd>SPACE</kbd> without any unwanted trailing spaces in the value;

Disadvantages:

- the quotation marks become part of the value, which may be disturbing in numerous situations;
- the command extensions need to be enabled for this syntax to work; otherwise, an error arises;
- special characters (like `^` `&` etc.) in `value` may cause problems; this is because of the way the command parser works: as soon as the first `"` is encountered, any special characters are no longer recognised, they are treated as literal characters; after the next `"`, special character recognition becomes re-activated, and so on; regard that this is also true in case `value` itself contains any quotation marks on its own;

---

#### Side Note:

Never put spaces around the equal-to sign in a `set` command line, because they will become part of the variable name and/or value. For instance, the command lines

```
set VAR = value
```

and

```
set "VAR = value"
```

both assign the string value <kbd>SPACE</kbd>`value` to a variable named `VAR`<kbd>SPACE</kbd>.